# SendGrid API Dynamic - can't get Unsubscribe to work

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I just set-up a dynamic email with sendgrid and am using the API to fill it out based on my customer data.

I've gotten everything to work except the unsubscribe part.

I have an unsubscribe block at the bottom of my email. In the code editor, the code looks like this:

```html
<div data-role="module-unsubscribe" class="module" role="module" data-type="unsubscribe" style="color:#444444; font-size:12px; line-height:20px; padding:16px 16px 16px 16px; text-align:center;" data-muid="67cd14f7-ddbf-421a-a070-57b3b3e6ccac"><p style="font-size:12px; line-height:20px;"><a class="Unsubscribe--unsubscribeLink" href="{{unsubscribe}}" target="_blank" style="">Unsubscribe</a></p></div></td>
```

I didn't edit the code, that's just how it came. But when I send the email (test or otherwise), the unsubscribe is not a link. Do I need to pass something for {{unsubscribe}} in the API request? If so, what would I pass?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

When you send an email with unsubscribe links, you need to include the [unsubscribe group](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/unsubscribe-groups) in the API request.

For example:

```js
client
  .send({
    to: "hello@example.com",
    from: "me@example.org",
    templateId: "YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID",
    dynamicTemplateData: { ... },
    asm: {
      groupId: "YOUR_UNSUBSCRIBE_GROUP_ID"
    }
  })
```

Make sure the `asm` key is in the root object, not in `personalizations`.

Comment: And what is the id of the Global group if I’d like to add the global unsubscribe?

Comment: Check out [the docs on group IDs here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/suppressions#groups).

Comment: Yup, I've read that doc already, but unfortunately, there's no reference to the "Global unsubscribe" group, which exists by default.

Comment: But it does say you can list your groups with the API. And that will likely show you all of them and their IDs.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div data-role="module-unsubscribe" class="module" role="module" data-type="unsubscribe" style="color:#444444; font-size:12px; line-height:20px; padding:16px 16px 16px 16px; text-align:center;" data-muid="67cd14f7-ddbf-421a-a070-57b3b3e6ccac"><p style="font-size:12px; line-height:20px;"><a class="Unsubscribe--unsubscribeLink" href="{{unsubscribe}}" target="_blank" style="">Unsubscribe</a></p></div></td>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).