# Templates Dynamic - can't get Unsubscribe to work

Tags: python, sendgrid

I have dynamic templates setup for sendgrid using a Python backend and JS frontned and everything sends fine BUT the unsubcribe does not work. I have done a little digging and found a similar case [SendGrid API Dynamic - can't get Unsubscribe to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71445513/sendgrid-api-dynamic-cant-get-unsubscribe-to-work?newreg=bd068e9077d044cbbc4c86b47ddcc39a) which would be great but it isn't Python. Sendgrid support does not want to touch code and even the library and docs make it hard for me to find an asm unsubscribe variable for me to pass the group id. Here is my current code with the API call in the backend.

```
def send_emails(recipient_emails, template_id):
    sg = SendGridAPIClient(api_key=sendgrid_key)
    for recipient_email in recipient_emails:
        print("Sending email to:", recipient_email)
        message = Mail(
            from_email="info@info",
            to_emails=recipient_email,
        )
        message.template_id = template_id
        try:
            response = sg.send(message)
            print(f"Email sent to {recipient_email} - Status Code: {response.status_code}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to send email to {recipient_email}: {str(e)}")
        time.sleep(1)  # Wait for one second before sending the next email
```

Here is the official python library https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/tree/main I have literally spent a day looking through this and have yet to find anything.

I tried looking through docs, talking to sendgrid support, and looking at library examples.

Answer (score 0):

The unsubscribe documentation is lacking. Add:

```
message.asm = Asm(GroupId(XXXXX))
```

with the XXXXX being the ID of the Unsubscribe group from sendgrid. You need to make sure that you also import Asm and GroupId from sendgrid.helpers.mail

```
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Asm, GroupId
```

Note, that you will also want to edit the html of your dynamic template to take out the "Unsubscribe" link and only have the "Unsubscribe Preferences" link (basically makes it a 2-step unsubscribe method). Otherwise, most email clients will click check and automatically unsubscribe.